# Unexpected Status of SSLEngineResult after an unwrap() operation

Tags: websocket

I am using websocket to receive server push data,but the client aways close with this message(`Unexpected Status of SSLEngineResult after an unwrap() operation`) and I could find noting about why this happen,I aways open as much as 50-200 websocket connection.This is my code:

```
     /**
     * Callback hook for Connection close events.
     *
     * @param userSession the userSession which is getting closed.
     * @param reason      the reason for connection close
     */
    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session userSession, CloseReason reason) {
        try {
            // do something
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("close websocket error", e);
        }
    }
```

this is the log:

```
2019-08-15 18:33:25.256  INFO 1039 --- [WebSocketClient-SecureIO-1] c.s.s.r.w.c.WebsocketClientEndpoint      : user：7871 exit,closing websocket,reason:{"closeCode":"CLOSED_ABNORMALLY","reasonPhrase":"Unexpected Status of SSLEngineResult after an unwrap() operation"}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server side closed the connection when have not receive the heartbeat of client,add the Ping & Pong heartbeat:

```
    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session userSession) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    String data = "Ping";
                    ByteBuffer payload = ByteBuffer.wrap(data.getBytes());
                    if (userSession != null) {
                        userSession.getBasicRemote().sendPing(payload);
                        log.info("send heartbeat");
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    log.error("send heartbeat error", e);
                }
            }
        };
        ScheduledFuture<?> scheduledFuture = executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(r, 5, 120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
```

Comment: I have implemented ping pong mechanism but still getting random disconnects, any idea why?

Comment: make sure the ping pong works. does the server disconnect the web socket proactive? please recheck. the ping pong mechanism  works for me actually.